# remove string between < and > special charactors after first white space in XML parsed string using python regular expression

Tags: python, string, xml-parsing, python-re

I have XML string like below.
Need to remove bold content using python regular expression. The content is between <,> and after first white space.

I have tried,

```
xml_data = f.read()
xml_data = re.sub(r"\<.*?\>","<>",xml_data)
```

But it was removing all the content in between <,>.

```
   <listEmp:department **internalId="32"**>
      <platformCore:name **xmlns:platformCore="urn:core_2017_1.platform.webservices.com"**>Sales : Sales Management (Local)</platformCore:name>
   </listEmp:department>
   <listEmp:location **internalId="2"**>
      <platformCore:name **xmlns:platformCore="urn:core_2017_1.platform.webservices.com"**>South Africa - Johannesburg</platformCore:name>
   </listEmp:location>
```

Comment: Don't use regular expressions to process XML, use an XML parser library like Beautiful Soup.

Comment: Where in your code do you try to remove attributes? You're just matching everything between `<>`. This doesn't look like you made a true attempt to solve your problem. You just posted some code in the hopes that we would do the work for you.

Comment: You say you want to remove text after whitespace, but your regexp has no whitespace in it!

Comment: Use a capture group to match everything from `<` to the first space. Then you can copy that to the result, which will remove everything after the space.

Comment: First I converted XML to string. After that only am using Py regular expression.

Comment: And where is the regexp that tries do do what you want? This code is not a sincere attempt to solve your problem, it's just a random regexp that has nothing to do with what you want.

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code resolve the issue.

```
xml_content = re.sub('<(\w+):(\w*).*?>',r'<\1:\2>',xml_data,flags=re.DOTALL)
```

And output looks like:

```
<listEmp:department>
      <platformCore:name>Sales : Sales Management (Local)</platformCore:name>
   </listEmp:department>
   <listEmp:location>
      <platformCore:name>South Africa - Johannesburg</platformCore:name>
   </listEmp:location>
```

And below piece of code change the XML content to:

```
tree = re.sub('<(\w+).*?>',r'<\1>',tree,flags=re.DOTALL)

   <department internalId="32">
      <name xmlns:platformCore="urn:core_2017_1.platform.webservices.com">Sales : Sales Management (Local)</name>
   </department>
```

Result XML content:

```
   <department>
      <name>Sales : Sales Management (Local)</name>
   </department>
```